# Draw epipolar lines for spherical images with known pose

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a couple of spherical images, given in equirectangular projection, looking at the same object from different positions. I know the absolute pose of each image e.g. position in geographical coordinates and roll/pitch/yaw angles. Given the pixel coordinate of a point in one image I would like to find a way to draw the epipolar line (where the correspondent point lies) in the other one.

I tried to deal with Essential/Fundamental matrix in python using OpenCV but I did'nt figure out how to achieve this.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you are having homologue points in both images (e.g. extracted through feature detection and matching) you could use `cv::findFundamentalMat` to extract the Fundamental matrix F and after that you can use `cv::computeCorrespondEpilines` with F to compute the epipolar line for any point in that image.

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. My problem is that I don't have homologue points to find the fundamental matrix; I guess if it's possible to use position/orientation info to calculate it.

Comment: If you calibrated your cameras you could use [this](https://sourishghosh.com/2016/fundamental-matrix-from-camera-matrices/).
Down the page there is the equation to calculate the fundamental matrix from a given rotation and translation for two calibrated cameras K1, K2. A different form can be found in Hartley, Zisserman p. 244.